# Python: Map lists to other ones that are newly ordered

Tags: python, list, dictionary, mapping

I have a list of let's say letters:

```
l1 = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"]
```

and two lists of values

```
x1 = [8,2,4,4,3,5,6,7,7,1]
y1 = [2,1,8,1,4,5,9,2,1,2]
```

I would like to find the simplest way to create a new list l2 that gives letters in the way the lists x2 and y2 are newly ordered:

```
x2 = [1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,7,8]
y2 = [2,1,4,1,8,5,9,2,1,2]
```

I tried some comprehension dictionary, by creating a link between values of (x1,y1) and  l1,which didn't work for now.

**Edit 1**

The output I want is having l2 as follows:

```
l2 = ["j","b","e","d","c","f","g","h","i","a"]
```

**Edit 2**

It seems that I wasn't really clear sorry on the way I wanted l2 to map l1. The idea is that I have x1 and y1 that are two lists of numbers, along with l1, that is a list of letters. I want to create a list l2 that has an output following the ordering of the numbers in x2 and y2 (that are the same in comparison with x1 and y1).

What I didn't mentioned is that l2 must be a transformation of l1 in the way (x2,y2) transform (x1,y1). My example was confusing because I choose a not random x2 list, but it could be in any order. We have to know x2 and y2!

I introduced two lists x1 and y1 because we sometimes have the same values in x1 (two 4 and two 7) and we need to consider the two lists to make it a one-to-one mapping.

Comment: I don't understand the question after three reads. For starters, what's the relevance of `x1` and `y1` to the question? Also you didn't post the result-list `l2` you want.

Comment: How are you expecting someone to help with this? the pattern of the new reordered list seems completely arbitrary.

Comment: It looks like x2 is the sorted x1, and the indices that get relocated in x1 also apply to y1, which results in y2. But after more than three reads, I still can't figure what is list l2.

Comment: I added in Edit 2 the explanation on how is (x2,y2) related to (x1,y2) in a one-to-one mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to achieve my goal, which might be a bit cumbersome.

```
x1_y1 = []
for i in range(len(x1)):
    x1_y1.append([x1[i],y1[i]])

x2_y2 = []
for i in range(len(x1)):
    x2_y2.append([x2[i],y2[i]])

def ordering(x1_y1,x2_y2,u):

    order_list_map = {(xx,yy):k for k,(xx,yy) in enumerate(x2_y2)}
    ubis = u.copy()
    for i in range(len(u)):
        ubis[i] = (u[i], order_list_map[(x1_y1[i][0],x1_y1[i][1])])
    ubis.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
    new_list = ubis.copy()
    for i in range(len(ubis)):
        new_list[i] = new_list[i][0]
    return new_list

l2 = ordering(x1_y1,x2_y2,l1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The question asks, given this list `l1`, and a list of values `l2`, how can I reorder the values in `l2` and apply the same permutation in `l1`?

```
from operator import itemgetter

l1 = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"]
x1 = [8,2,4,4,3,5,6,7,7,1]
y1 = [2,1,8,1,4,5,9,2,1,2]

values = list(zip(x1, l1, y1))
values.sort(key=itemgetter(0))
x2, l2, y2 = zip(*values)
```

The first line after the declaration gives you a list of triplets. The sort function using `key=itemgetter(0)`, is slightly more complex. It uses the `itemgetter` function to return a function that selects the 0th value from an object that is indexable, i.e. tuple, list, or dict. The third line unpacks the elements into the lists that you wanted.

You can then modify the `key=function` argument to your liking to get different permutations.

Comment: I edited the question to make it clearer. I would like to be able to order x1 and y1 from values of x2 and y2, and not only in the very specific case where x2 is ascending.

Comment: To do that then you need to permutate a list of indices using x1 and x2, then use the list of indices to select values from l1.

Comment: Could you please give an example of how to do that?